# Couldn't upload image file using "Choose File" keyword in robot framework. How to handle image upload validations using robot framework?

Tags: robotframework

I am trying to validate the image upload functionality for my application using robot framework, I have my script as follows:

```
*** Variables ***
${browse}              xpath=//*[@id="file"]
${path_jpg}            ${EXECDIR}\\test_data\\Browse_Image\\apple.jpg
${path_png}            ${EXECDIR}\\test_data\\Browse_Image\\apple.png
${path_gif}            ${EXECDIR}\\test_data\\Browse_Image\\apple.gif
${path_webm}           ${EXECDIR}\\test_data\\Browse_Image\\apple.ppt

Choose File  ${browse}  ${path_jpg}
```

The script runs fine in chrome, But in case of firefox and edge, Error message is thrown as follows:

Firefox:

> ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element `<input id="file" type="file">` is not reachable by keyboard**

Edge:

> WebDriverException: Message: The element is not focusable

How to handle this?

Comment: How does it react if you put small wait after {browse} ?

Comment: @ponkape's idea to wait is a good suggestion but I would add `Sleep    5s` before the `Choose File` keyword. This way you can be sure that the previous action does not interfere with your `Choose File` step.

Comment: Adding a Sleep doesn't work, Same error is thrown **ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <input id="file" type="file"> is not reachable by keyboard**

Comment: What version of FF / Edge do you have? Latest geckodriver ?